# Node express sqlite3 . When I use a service for the DB query I get nothing back

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use a sqlite3 database for a node.js express. If I return the request as in the tutorial in router.js it works and I get all the items. Now I have created a service to get the sql from the route (controller). But unfortunately I don't get anything back. I had already tried it with async await in the service. That didn't help either.

**my code:**

```js
// router.js

const dbService = require("../services/dbService/");

router.get("/users",  (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.status(200).send({
      data: dbService.getAllUsers();
    })
    return;
  } catch(err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

```js
// dbService.js

const db = require("../db/database.js");

module.exports = {
  getAllUsers() {
    const sql = "select * from users";
    db.all(sql,[], (err, rows) => {
      return {"data": rows};
    });
  }
}
```

For simple reasons, I have not included error handling in the code.  Why can't I get database values from the service? What do I have to do?

Thanks in advance! Mike

Comment: see: [Requesting promise from sqlite database, await is not returning anything and async function won't log anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71286652/requesting-promise-from-sqlite-database-await-is-not-returning-anything-and-asy)

Comment: @traynor Thank you! That helped. I had almost thought that I should put it in a promise.  Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: @traynor Do you want to write another answer? Since you helped me very quickly, I would like to mark your answer as accept.

Comment: thanks, well, since there are many solutions with explanations out there, there's not much for me to add, which is why I left a comment linking to the one that seems to be the most relevant, rather than answering

Comment: @traynor All right! Thank you! Have a good evening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running afoul of asynchronous JS. [`db.all`](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#allsql--param---callback) returns results to the callback.

A refactor to use callbacks would look something like:

```js
// router.js

const dbService = require("../services/dbService/");

router.get("/users",  (req, res, next) => {
  dbService.getAllUsers((err, result) => {
    if (err) next(err);
    res.json({
      data: result;
    });
  });
});


// dbService.js
const db = require("../db/database.js");

module.exports = {
  getAllUsers(cb) {
    const sql = "select * from users";
    db.all(sql,[], (err, rows) => {
      cb(err, rows);
    });
  }
}
```

And promises woudl look like:

```js
// router.js

const dbService = require("../services/dbService/");

router.get("/users", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
     const result = await dbService.getAllUsers();

     res.json({
        data: result;
     });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});


// dbService.js
const db = require("../db/database.js");

module.exports = {
  getAllUsers(cb) {
    const sql = "select * from users";
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      db.all(sql,[], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(rows);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your effort to show both variants. Which variant would you prefer?

Comment: A colleague had already left me a comment quite quickly with a correct reference to the solution. I'll wait until he writes another answer here. Then I would like to give him the accpt in fairness. I hope that is ok for you? If he doesn't want to then you get the accept. Thanks to you!

Comment: @MaikLowrey I typically favour `async/await` with promises, as heavy callback use can result in callback hell http://callbackhell.com/